# FindOne return different values in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Good afternoon, Please help with this, Please see below code

UserSchema.js

```
'use strict';
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const UsersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name:{
            type: String,
            unique : true
        },
    }
);

export default {
    UsersSchema
}
```

model.js

```
'use strict';

import mongoose from "mongoose";
import usersSchema from "./schemas/userSchema.js";

const model = mongoose.model;

const user = model('users', usersSchema);

export default {
    user,
}
```

user.js

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import userModel from "../models/models.js";

const getUser = async (event) => {
    try {
        const { name} = JSON.parse(event.body);
        console.log(await userModel.user.model)
        const user = await userModel.user.findOne({ name: name }).exec();
        console.log(user)

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
export default {
    getUser
}
```

I have two items in my mongodb but it always return the first value . But if i change it to findOne(_id), it will return the specific item/name.

Please help me

I want to return the same filtered item in findOne

Users Table
[image: Users Table]

Code sample
[image: Code sample]

Comment: It returns the first value and the name field does not match your query ?

Comment: Please provide yous sample data collection

Comment: For example, I have two items(jane and joe) , I query it using jane, but the return value is always john, even if I misspelled it, it returns same value